# Microsoft products Link to open in notepad not default

Tags: windows, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to create a link in any Microsoft product (specifically OneNote, but I would assume that it would be the same for all Microsoft products) so that the item I want to open will open in a different program other than the default that Windows is set to open it in?

Example: A .bat file needs to be edited so in my OneNote documentation I say: "Please modify THIS file to add your blah blah blah". I highlight "THIS" right click, Link... and if this was a txt file I would just put in the address "file:////[file path]", but I want to open a .bat file, which, if I just put file://// would execute the .bat in a new command window. This is NOT what I want.

I have tried to create another .bat file with "start notepad %1" and the address in my OneNote "file:////[path]\start_with_notepad.bat some.bat" but OneNote doesnt like parameters like that, AND I get a warning ".bat files are unsafe, blah blah" when it tries to run. I don't want warnings.

[What I see when trying to link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMEDp.jpg)

[What I see when drag/drop a shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ng4.jpg)

Comment: So, you're not talking about shortcuts on the desktop or elsewhere in the filesystem, but "URLS" in documents or files? And you want to be able to open the URL in software not necessarily set as default? You need to look into protocols, as used in Windows, link security in the application you're dealing with, and opening files in applications via the command line.

Comment: Just create a shortcut to the app + the full path to the fie, e.g. *notepad "C:\Users\Tizzle\Desktop\MyFile.bat"*

Comment: @music2myear I want to just open .bat file with notepad via the Link in OneNote, as if the .bat file was a .txt file. Im not sure I understand why I would need the command line.

Comment: @DrMoishe As soon as I put a space after "notepad" in the Address text box, the OK grays out. I assume you cannot do that.

Comment: I played around with this for a couple minutes earlier. OneNote uses the file:/// protocol when you select notepad.exe in the hyperlink dialog, and adding a file path argument after broke the link. I'm assuming there's a way to make it work using protocols, but it's not the same as a shortcut on a desktop.

Comment: Oh, wait. In OneNote you can embed pretty much anything. So just create a shortcut on your desktop that opens Notepad and opens the batfile IN that Notepad, then drop that lnk file into OneNote. I'll test this tomorrow and write up an answer if it works.

Comment: I have done that, and put "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe \\networkpath\SETENV.bat" as the Target of the shortcut. When running it on my desktop, it works as expected, but not when i drag/drop it into OneNote. It seems it copies the notepad executable, and not the shortcut (added picture)

Comment: Oh, too bad. Yea, I'm trying that right now myself and like you said, it isn't working. So it's back to protocols. Windows handles categories of links using "protocols". http:// and file:// are two examples of protocols. I'd imagine that we'd have to figure how to pass arguments in protocols to make this work. I could be wrong, but that's my best guess right now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into protocols. I would think that is the best as well. Or, this was never implemented and there is no clean way of doing it. Thats a possibility too.